# Python binary arithmetic

Tags: python, math, binary

I've been doing binary arithmetic in Python.  It seems clumsy to me probably because there is a better way.  The sample code provided creates a binary digit list, creates the reverse list and create the absolute difference.  any suggestions for better technique will be appreciated.

```
 for (i, j, k, n, m) in [(i, j, k, n, m)for i in range(2) for j in range(2) \
                for k in range(2)for n in range(2) for m in range(2)]:

s = [i, j, k, n, m]  # binary sequence
r = s[::-1]      # reversed sequence

sbin = '0b'      # create binary number as string
rbin = '0b'
for a in range(5):
    sbin += str(s[a])
    rbin += str(r[a])

sbb = int(sbin,2)  # create binary number
rbb = int(rbin,2)
v = abs(sbb - rbb)  # take absolute difference as integers

dif = bin(v)            # convert back to binary
print(sbin, rbin, dif, v)
```

Comment: misspelled binary in title sorry about that, probably limits responses

Answer (score 1):

this is an option:

```
BITSIZE = 5

for i in range(1<<BITSIZE):
    a = i
    b = 0
    for k in range(BITSIZE):  # b = reversed_bits(a)
        b <<= 1
        b ^= i&1
        i >>= 1
    print('   {:05b} {:05b}'.format(a, b))
    print(a, b, abs(a-b))
```

instead of enumerating the individual bits, the first loop counts from `0` to `2^5-1` (`1<<5` shifts a bit up 5 places which equals to `2^5`). the rest is just a matter of reversing the bits (the loop over `k`).

this outputs:

```
   00000 00000
0 0 0
   00001 10000
1 16 15
   00010 01000
2 8 6
   00011 11000
3 24 21
   00100 00100
4 4 0
   00101 10100
5 20 15
...
   11110 01111
30 15 15
   11111 11111
31 31 0
```

the binary operations of python can be seen here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

---

as pointed out by [Reti43](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2243104/reti43) this could be written a little more compact:

```
BITSIZE = 5
for a in range(1<<BITSIZE):
    b = 0
    for k in range(BITSIZE):  # b = reversed_bits(a)
        b = (b << 1) | ((a >> k) & 1)
    print(a, b, abs(a-b))
```

Comment: In my opinion, `for k in range(BITSIZE): b = (b << 1) | ((a >> k) & 1)` is more direct and clear.

Comment: @Reti43 updated the answer to include your bit-reversing algorithm. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As your absolute difference technique demonstrates, integer arithmetic is already done in binary, and so that should be leveraged as much as possible.  Although there may be issues with signed quantities.

I would claim your nested 5 deep list comprehension simply generates the numbers from 1 to 31 in binary so why not `s = range(32)` do any arithmetic as integer arithmetic and use `bin` to get the binary string on the result.

Reversing a string of digits is not generally a common thing done for binary arithmetic, but poses an interesting problem with a relatively easy solution.  The following function has no error checking as it assumes you will only pass in valid output of the `bin` function.  It takes into account that binary representation always starts with '0b' and you do not want that to be reversed.

```
def reverse_binstr(b):
    return b[0:2] + b[:1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your own code, you can avoid some unnecesary variables and simplify the iteration:

```
from itertools import product
BITS = ('0','1')

for s in product(*[BITS]*5):
    sbin = ''.join(s)
    diff = abs(int(sbin, 2) - int(sbin[::-1], 2))
    print (sbin, sbin[::-1], diff, bin(diff))
```

Making it look less clumsy. I like hiro's answer though. Very elegant and perhaps way faster. But it has a lot to digest for me.

Comment: I thank you posters for your great code examples.  I learned something new from each post.